# Python Selenium- Message: binary is not a Firefox executable with portable Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using:
Selenium 4.2 (Python)

Geckodriver 0.32.0

Portable Firefox 107 installed on a USB key

Pycharm installed on the same USB key

The below code (run via Pycharm on the USB) gives me: "Message: binary is not a Firefox executable with portable Firefox".

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/"

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'X:\Browser\FirefoxPortable\firefoxPortable.exe'

service = Service(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

Any idea why ? if I use the .exe of the firefox installed on my machine (C:) it does work. Thanks !

Comment: I'd guess that it doesn't support launching in dev-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Because firefoxPortable.exe is probably in custom launcher format geckodriver.exe does not recognize it as a browser.

**Possible solution:**

Navigate to the executable directly **"\App\Firefox64\firefox.exe"**

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/"

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'X:\Browser\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox64\firefox.exe'

service = Service(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```